# i need to write a code in perl/java which prints a name 100 times in a1 second

Tags: java, perl

Can any one please help me to write a code in perl/java that prints a name 100 times in 1 second.

Comment: try a for loop... more detail needed to get a better answer e.g. where are you getting your name from, where are you printing to, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: If you don't have a more specific question, I suggest you buy a book about Java or Perl and read the first 4 chapters.

Comment: Is this homework? The answer is a bit to easy to reveal. Perhaps if you could specify where you are having difficulty. Otherwise read the first few chapters in anybook in perl or java.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful what you wish for.

```
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
my $how_many_times = 100;
my $how_long       = 1; # second
my $name           = 'amit';

for (1..$how_many_times) {
    sleep $how_long / $how_many_times;
    print $name;
}
```

Comment: This executes in 1.03 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Sleep sets the minimum time to sleep.  It's not guaranteed to take exactly the time requested.

Comment: You must not measure the set-up time. The `for` loop executes in 1.006 seconds, that's accurate enough.

Comment: Hi, When i am calculating the execution time using the function use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);    it comes more than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

for loop can be executed in less than 1 second to print a name 100 times in java/perl on a good machine.

Comment: Even on a terrible machine 100 prints takes < 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the simplest way (but maybe not enough):

```
String name = "name";
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(name);
        wait(10);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

UPDATE: Better, use [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: While the above does demonstrate a for loop in Java. It will make you wait for 10 seconds on each call. 10*100 seconds is too much time. See if you can figure out how to speed it up.

Comment: @jones - This will take about 1 second. [Object.wait(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) is in milliseconds.

Comment: @jones, 10 milliseconds [Object.wait(long timeout)](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))